# List nodes with Views 2 module, despite nodes having restricted permissions

Tags: views, users

My nodes have individual Access Control permissions.

I need anonymous users to be able to see a View (giving them a preview essentially) of these nodes, but currently they don't have access.

Is there an easy way to override the permissions just for this View, and show the nodes anyway? Searching for a solution lists a workaround which only works in Views 3.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to update to Views 3? Because in views 3, under the **Advanced** > **Other** section you can change the **Query settings** options and make sure the **Disable SQL rewriting** checkbox is checked.

Comment: I realise that. The site is dependant upon many Views extension modules, some of which are only compatible with Views 2. If I upgrade I'll have additional problems.